the display header type doesn't match, and I need to read both the js file and the html file, what should I do？
I'm a programming learner.,I found lottie at the beginning of the year.,I found that I can AE and front-end at the same time.,That's very convenient for me.,So I'm going to try to use it this vacation.,But I found that it's just html,css,javascript will have cross-domain restrictions.,Asked GPT I used to build a server.,And then it happened that I would be part of the node.js.,I used node.js.,But it always gets an error.,The problem is now：
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
I'm really sad that today is the third day.
enter image description here
Here is the code for a file named node_index.js
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

const server = http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    const filePath = `${__dirname}/index.html`;
    fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
        res.end("404,有问题");
        return;
      }
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/html",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
        Pragma: "no-cache",
        Expires: 0,
      });
      res.end(data);
    });
  })
  .listen(8000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:8000/`);
  })
  .on("error", (err) => {
    console.error("Server error:", err);
  });

Here is the code for the file named index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="animation_box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="myscript.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>

enter image description here

You need a web server to run the index.html file, and the server must be properly handle files like myscript.js.
Forget the node_index.js NodeJS web server, and simply use this VS Code plugin named Live Server instead.

I see, I actually have the VScode plugin of the live server, but in the case of abandoning the node.js server, I always get an error, and I used the node.js after asking GPT, and the error is below                                             1.Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Yulia/OneDrive/%E5%89%8D%E7%AB%AF/2024.8.05/myscript.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge.       2. Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

@voiles As I said, forget that node.js server. Never use that again. Is that CORS error still there when you use LiveServer plugin?

I'm pretty sure yes.And I've heard that Express can solve this problem better. So I'm going to solve this problem after learning Express.(❁´◡`❁)
